# How to check if Directory already Exists in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How to check if Directory already Exists in MFC(VC++) ?
I am using below code to get current application Path and there i am creating NDSLog folder 
so that all my Logfiles should place there , now i want to check the condition if NDSLog folder already exists dont create it .How to do that ?

Thanks.

```
char strPathName[_MAX_PATH];
    ::GetModuleFileName(NULL, strPathName, _MAX_PATH);

    // The following code will allow you to get the path.
    CString newPath(strPathName);
    int fpos = newPath.ReverseFind('\\');

    if (fpos != -1)
    newPath = newPath.Left(fpos+1);     
    newPath += "NDSLog\\" ;

    CreateDirectory(newPath,NULL);
```

Comment: Can I just interject a plea to NOT put your logs under the current directory? On Vista and Windows 7, a non-elevated (ordinary in other words) application can't write anywhere under Program Files. Since you're writing this code today, and you're writing for Windows, please use AppData ( CSIDL_APPDATA ) for your logs. Create a subdirectory for your app and if you like another under that for the logs.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The simplest way to check if a file/directory exists is to use [`GetFileAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364944%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
if (GetFileAttributes(newPath) == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) {
  CreateDirectory(newPath,NULL);
}
```

Note that the function will return `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES` even if it fails due to some other reason, such as not having permissions to access the file, so you should check the return value of `CreateDirectory` to make sure that it succeeded.

Actually, you don't need to check whether the directory already exists; `CreateDirectory` will set an error code if the directory already exists:

```
if (!CreateDirectory(newPath,NULL)) {
  if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) {
    // directory already exists
  } else {
    // creation failed due to some other reason
  }
}
```

Comment: Both solutions do *not* take into account, that there may be a (regular) file with the same name as the directory to create: The first approach (`GetFileAttributes()`) should add a check if the "directory" attribute is set in case the return value != `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`. Then the directory really exists already. Otherwise a regular file with the same name will prevent the directory from being created. Same for second approach: `CreateDirectory()` returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` if a regular file (not a directory) already exists.

Answer (score 3):

How about [`PathIsDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773621(v=vs.85).aspx)? In the original example, you can use `PathRemoveFilespec()` followed by `PathCombine()` to add a new filename/extension. In the unlikely case that your target is only Windows 8 or later, there are safer `PathCch...()` flavors of these functions.

Answer (score 1):

I use PathFileExists.

Answer (score 0):

[`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx). Despite the "File" in the name, it'll find directories perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use _accees or _waccess from C runtime. 
[This is the msdn page and you can see sample usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)
And also you don't have to wory about if directory already exist because CreateDirectory checks and returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS if exists. [You can see from here (Return Codes).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I must note, that GetFileAttributes work slow when file is a network path.
Actually, it works slow for the first time, and fast afterwards.